# ¿Es seguro usar nombres de tablas como literales dentro del código PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, seguridad

Llevo más de un año programando con PHP y MySQL en proyectos pequeños. Cuando quiero mostrar datos de una base de datos en un select, en una tabla, o lo que sea, incluyo un archivo php y ya sea mediante POO o directamente hago las consultas a las bases de datos.

Ejemplo: `"select * from table"`

Mi pregunta está orientada a saber si es seguro hacerlo así. Yendo a un caso extremo, *¿las grandes plataformas literalmente tienen así las sentencias, con los nombres de las tablas literalmente como un string?*

En definitiva,
¿Qué tipo de seguridad se puede manejar para que nadie llegue a esos strings con esos datos tan importantes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya que usas PHP y con mi corta experiencia puedo decir que es necesario para medidas de seguridad utilizar PDO:

```
$servidor = 'mysql:dbname=base;host=127.0.0.1';
$usuario = 'usuario';
$contraseña = 'contraseña';
try {
$gbd = new PDO($servidor, $usuario, $contraseña);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'Falló la conexión: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Ademas de Procedimientos Almacenados para evitar como lo explicas escribir el query en tu consulta:

```
$mysqli->query("CREATE PROCEDURE storedprocedure(IN id INT) BEGIN INSERT INTO base(id) VALUES(id_val); END;")
```

Nota que en esta Parte es importante usar Mysqli, para evitar la Inyeccion SQL.

Para llamar a tu procedimiento:

```
if (!$mysqli->query("CALL storedprocedure(1)")) {
echo "Error (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
```

Comment: "_Nota que en esta Parte es importante usar Mysqli **y las sentencias preparadas**, para evitar la Inyeccion SQL._".